# change bootstrap navbar default dimensions with css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

here i have a bootstrap navbar with right aligned logo and left aligned links with social media icons. This is the html:

```
<!--=========NAVBAR=========-->
            <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                    <div class="container-fluid">

                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                          </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a class="nav-link" href="">About</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
```

And I have changed the height and i have centered vertically the items with the following css:

```
.navbar {
    min-height: 80px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:none;
    transition: 1s all ease;
}

.navbar-brand{
    min-height: 80px;
    padding: 18.5px 0 18.5px 20px;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a.nav-link {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 26.5px 20px;
    line-height: 27px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:white;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.navbar .navbar-right > li > a.fa{
    padding: 26.5px 0 26.5px 20px;
    line-height: 27px;    
    font-size: 27px;
    color:white;
}

.navbar .nav > li:nth-child(5){
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    padding-right:15px;
}

.navbar .nav > li:nth-child(6){
    padding-left:15px;
}

.navbar .nav > li:nth-child(8){
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

the navbar has 80px height, the  tags have line heigh of 27 px. so 80-27 = 53px remaining which means the  tags have 53/2 = 26.5px padding top and 26.5px padding to the bottom. that's how i center them vertically. same logic with the logo image. the image is 43px hight which means 37 remaing so 18.5 padding top and 18.5 padding bottom. The question is is my logic right? Do I have any unnecessary css rules? i want to add an effect that when i scroll down the navbar becomes shorter but i have paddings etc in many elements so i cant just add a class dynamicaly with javascript i have to change all these paddings in 3 different elements. So is there any faster way of doing it? Here is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use another class which represents the alternate state of the `.navbar`. Because the `.navbar` **IS** the **common ancestor** of the `.navbar-brand`, `.navbar .nav > li > a.nav-link`, and `.navbar .navbar-right > li > a.fa` elements.

Then we can just toggle the modifier class using JavaScript. Here's a working example. Using the `.squished` modifier class

```
<html>
  <head>


    <title>Our Simple Solution</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

        .navbar {
            min-height: 80px;
            background-color: red; /* changed bg for better visual */
            border: none;
            /* transition: 1s all ease; */
        }

        .navbar-brand {
            min-height: 80px;
            padding: 18.5px 0 18.5px 20px;
        }

        .navbar .nav > li > a.nav-link {
            font-family: "Dosis", sans-serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 600;
            padding: 26.5px 20px;
            line-height: 27px;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: white;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
        }

        .navbar .navbar-right > li > a.fa {
            padding: 26.5px 0 26.5px 20px;
            line-height: 27px;
            font-size: 27px;
            color: white;
        }

        .navbar .nav > li:nth-child(5) {
            border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
            padding-right: 15px;
        }

        .navbar .nav > li:nth-child(6) {
            padding-left: 15px;
        }

        .navbar .nav > li:nth-child(8) {
            padding-right: 20px;
        }


        /* ADDED CSS RULES */
        .navbar,
        .navbar-brand,
        .navbar .nav > li > a.nav-link,
        .navbar .navbar-right > li > a.fa {
            transition: 1s all ease;
        }


        .navbar.squished {
            min-height: 60px; /* example unit */
        }

        .navbar.squished .navbar-brand {
            min-height: 60px; /* example unit */
            padding: 8.5px 0 8.5px 20px;
        }

        .navbar.squished .nav > li > a.nav-link {
            padding: 16.5px 20px;
        }

        .navbar.squished .navbar-right > li > a.fa {
            padding: 16.5px 0 16.5px 20px;
        }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- ORIGINAL MARKUP --> 
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="image could not be loaded"><!-- added [alt] attribute --></a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Blog</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!--// ORIGINAL MARKUP --> 

    <!-- SOME SCROLLABLE CONTENT --> 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conpsectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ea, saepe sapiente quidem debitis est id accusantium ipsam officiis. Beatae commodi odit ab optio quas, incidunt architecto natus officiis quis!</p>
    <!--// SOME SCROLLABLE CONTENT --> 



    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var nav = document.querySelector('.navbar');
            var body = document.body;
            document.onscroll = function(event) {
                //console.log(body.scrollTop);

                if (body.scrollTop > nav.offsetHeight) { // nav current height
                    nav.classList.add('squished');
                }
                else {
                    nav.classList.remove('squished');
                }

            };
        })();


        /* OR JQUERY EQUIVALENT */

        /*$(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).scroll(function(event) {
                var $nav = $('.navbar').eq(0);
                var $body = $(this.body);
                //console.log(body.scrollTop);

                if ($body.scrollTop() > $nav.height()) {
                    $nav.addClass('squished');
                }
                else {
                     $nav.removeClass('squished');
                }

            });
        })*/
    </script>
  </body>  
</html>
```